# Alternative to System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString that uses a case-insensitive comparer?

Tags: c#, querystringparameter, namevaluecollection

If you include a query string on the HREF of the "Launch" link on the `publish.htm` page that ClickOnce generates when you publish a Windows desktop application:

```
        HREF="MyWindowsApp.application?ARG1=sis&ARG2=boom&ARG3=bah"
```

then the query string can be accessed and parsed inside the Windows program:

```
      if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
            string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
            nameValueColl = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);               
        }
```

But the **NameValueCollection** that the `HttpUtility` parser returns is case-sensitive. A parameter won't be found if you test for it using the wrong case:

```
        if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
            string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
            nameValueColl = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString); 
            if (nameValueColl.AllKeys.Contains("arg1")  ) 
                 {
                     // we don't get here
                 }         ​
       ​}
```

Is there an alternative to `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`  that uses a case-insensitive comparer?

Comment: `ParseQueryString()` doesn't care about case. It just returns what's given. Characters are characters, after all, and there's no such things as a case-insensitve string. It's  Instead, think more about how `AllKeys.Contains()` works.

Comment: Also note that case-insensitive comparison is culture-specific. How would you make sure that the same culture is used on client and server?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  : Yes, it's easy enough to loop through the keys and do a string compare with the `ignoreCase` parameter set to true, but if there was already Microsoft code that did this, so much the better; one less routine.